# How can i use node packages in claudiajs for use it in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-twitter

How can I use node packages in claudiajs. I tried to use node-twitter-api and node-twitter in it but getting blank response.
promise will require or not i have no idea about it in lambda.
if any one has any examples or documents that may have multiple node packages used with claudiajs for lambda. reference: http://claudia.js , https://vimeo.com/156232471

```
  var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder'),
  api = new ApiBuilder();
  var twitterAPI = require('node-twitter-api');
  var Promise = require("bluebird");
  api.get("/request-token", function(request) {
        'use strict';
         new Promise(function(resolve) {
             var twitter = new twitterAPI({
                consumerKey: "ckey",
                consumerSecret: "cskey",
                callback: 'http://localhost:3000/access-token'
             });
             var res;
             twitter.getRequestToken(function(err, requestToken, requestSecret) {      
                 if (err)
                     res = err;
                 else {
                     var _requestSecret = requestSecret;
                     var url = "https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token" + requestToken;
                     res = url;        
                     //res.redirect(url);
                 }
             });
             return res;
         });
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on how to make it easy for people to answer. In this case you have dumped a heap of code without being specific about what you are trying to do, or where you think the problem might be. Nobody will be able to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use packages just by including into package.json, using the normal javascript NPM commands (eg `npm install <package-name> -S`, check out https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/packaging.html for more information), but based on your code this doesn't seem to be the problem.

- you should return the promise out of the handler. (you're just instantiating the promise, not returning it)
- no need to use bluebird, lambda uses node 4.3 which supports Promises out of the box
- twitter.getRequestToken seems to use a callback, you'll need to translate that back to the promise you're returning and resolve/reject the result. check out an intro on promises somewhere online, or just use denodeify to turn the callback function into a promise directly